# Change background color of MSMessage app icon slot

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension, msmessage

I am incorporating the iMessage extension in my app & for that I create the MSMessage instance when some content from my app needs to be sent. I have used the recommended iMessage app icon asset resolution .The app icon is displayed in the top left corner of the MSMessage View. The app icon slot is oval in shape & my app icon is center aligned. The remainder of the oval shape is black in color and frankly speaking, that makes it look HORRENDOUS!! Is there any way to change the background color of the oval shaped app icon slot ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely certain which icon you are referring to? Could you provide a screenshot or instructions of how to see it?

Comment: Why do you want to change the background color? instead create an app icon which fits that oval that will look more better.

Comment: @Fogmeister updated my question

Comment: @iYoung yeah that is a solution. Is there any alternative, is all I ask.

Comment: As far as I know you can't change the background color of that desired item.

Comment: @iYoung I'll take your word for it. Thanks.